# Counterpart to regression equivariance in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

Let $T(y_i,\pmb x_i)$ be a regression estimator (of the scalar $y_i$ unto 
the $p$-vector $\pmb x_i$). When $T$ is the usual LS estimator and $\nu\in\mathbb{R}^p$, we have that:

$$T(y_i+\pmb x_i'\pmb\nu,\pmb x_i)=T(y_i,\pmb x_i)+\pmb\nu$$

This property is called regression equivariance and plays much the same 
 role, in the linear regression context, as translation equivariance does 
in the context of multivariate estimators.

I was wondering whether there is a similar property (equivariance to a form of 
translation) for logistic regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In linear regression there exist two other types of equivariance: one about adding a linear function to the response (‘regression equivariance’) and one about multiplying the response by a constant factor (‘y-scale equivariance’), but these obviously do not apply to logistic regression.

Page 6 of the following document:

http://www.stoch.uni-bayreuth.de/de/CHRISTMANN/Christmann_files/ChristmannRousseeuw_wemel.pdf

The paper studies a different type of equivariance (page 6 as well):

> A property shared by all logistic regression estimators is $x$-affine equivariance.